# I need to list of all open handles

Tags: c#, c++, .net

i need to list all open handles ( openthread and openprocess ) from process i select i try to search but it's not help me out anymore.

ps. sorry for my bad english hope you understand me

thanks
Eazfuscator

Comment: Is the question about C++ or C#?

Comment: i think c# is better for me